# How to open a route in a separate component without unmounting the previous one in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm currently working on a recipe website with React JS and React router.

In the **HomePage**, I've got **a grid of cards**, and each card is a preview of a recipe.

Each card is wrapped in a `<Link></link>` tag. On clicking on one of these cards, I want to open another page (so the URL change and the component linked to the specific route opens, thanks to react-router). And on this new component, I show all the details about the recipe.

**My problem is** :
When I'm on the detail page and click on the "previous" button of the navigator, my grid component with all the recipes is mounted again. This is a problem because :

- **I don't want to fetch again all the recipes**
- **I'm losing the scroll level before clicking on a recipe**

I already thought about **implementing a modal**, which appears on screen when I click on a recipe card, and show all the details about the recipe (I tried that by changing the `<Link></link>` wrapping tag of each card with a simple div and an onClick action). This modal is over the grid component, therefore I don't lose the scroll level in the grid and I don't need to re-fetch all the datas. But with this solution, I lose all the navigation capabilities (can't go back with the "previous" button of the navigator, URL can only be modified artificially...)

Does anybody have a solution for this kind of situation?

**My concerned routes :**

```
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <Suspense fallback={<LoadingPage />}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <HomePage />  // recipes grid page
          </Route>
          <Route path="/recette/:id">
            <RecipeDetailPage />  // recipe details page
          </Route>
          <Route path="/not-found">
            <NotFoundPage />
          </Route>
          <Redirect to="/not-found" />
        </Switch>
      </Suspense>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};
```

**My recipe Card Component (these are in my grid component and clickable) :**

```
<Link className="RecipeCard__wrapper" to={`/recette/${recipe._id}`}>
// ... card datas
</Link>
```

**My recipe detail page :**
I check for the id of the recipe in the URL, and then fetch the corresponding recipe. Classic React component, nothing special.

Comment: Don't use `exact` and it won't unmount.

Answer (score 0):

you can render for both path same component:

```
<Route exact path="/">
  <Pages/>
</Route>
<Route path="/recette/:id">
  <Pages/>
</Route>
```

and use condition in component:

```
if(match.url.includes('recette') {
   <RecipeDetailPage />
} else {
   <HomePage />
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try that !